# Floppy Drive not recognised

Tags: drive, floppy

I am a newbie with Ubuntu during the past two weeks, and I believe, that I have made good progress so far. Current setup tasks are completed, like: "Wireless Network, Printer, Thunderbird + Firefox, e-mail", also my local weather station - all setup. Updated files and rearranged the desktop to my liking.

The problem I have now is my floppy drive which is not recognized, but the activity light is shown on constantly.

I have downloaded the "MakeFloppyDriveAvailableToEveryone" and i am confident that I can follow the instructions to change the floppy drive. However, I do not have an existing **fd0** file in `/dev/???`, but only `/dev/fd/` files **0** to **46**.

Please advise.

Comment: I would say that its extremely unusual for Ubuntu not to recognise a floppy drive by default. Are you sure your floppy drive is correctly cabled or that the cable itself is not an issue?  Its most unusual to see the activity light to be on constantly - that could point to a hardware issue not a software issue.

Comment: also, please check BIOS settings for your floppy drive

Answer (score 2):

The light staying on constantly is what happens when you plug in the drive cable backwards.

Comment: +1 - Yes, that's exactly right. Turn the cable around the other way.